# Amplitude at threshold

Tags: quantum-field-theory

So I'm working through a problem in Peskin & Schroeder QFT textbook (This one, 4.3b http://www.physics.umd.edu/grt/taj/624a/LinearSigmaModel.pdf).

I have to compute some scattering amplitudes and there's a term that somewhat confuses me. It's "amplitude at threshold"... I couldn't find an explicit definition anywhere. I just want to make sure I understand the meaning of that term.

Comment: The term is defined in part (c) of the problem. It means the soft limit, where all the pion 3-momenta are zero.

Comment: But it can also mean the energy threshold for that proccess... I checked a couple of solutions online and they all meant that. It is precisely the reason why I was confused enough to post the question in the first place.

Comment: I checked a solution, and it seems to agree with my comment and Peskin's definition.

Comment: Said another way, it's the lowest possible energy scale for the process. And that happens when the reactants have zero 3-momenta.

Comment: Aahhh yes, of course, it's all consistent, I see it now. Thank you!! Feel free to post it as the answer, I will accept it.